# Trying to display elapsed time each time lap button is clicked on five different labels xamarin

Tags: c#, if-statement, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im trying to make a stopwatch in Xamarin using C#.
I click start, time runs.
I click lap finished, it saves elapsed to displayLap1.
I click lap finished again, it saves the elapsed time to displayLap1 again instead on going to displayLap2.
I want to display each lap time on each label when lap button clicked.

```
    private void lapButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
        ts.Milliseconds / 10);


        
        displayLaps1.Text = stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString();
        
        if ((displayLaps1.Text != "") && (displayLaps2.Text == ""))
        {
            displayLaps2.Text = stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString();
        }
        //else if ((displayLaps1.Text != "") && (displayLaps2.Text != ""))
        //{
        //    displayLaps3.Text = stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString();
        //}
        //else if ((displayLaps1.Text != "") && (displayLaps2.Text != "") && (displayLaps3.Text != ""))
        //{
        //    displayLaps4.Text = stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString();
        //}
        //else if (displayLaps4.Text != "")
        //{
        //    displayLaps5.Text = stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString();
        //}

    }
```

Comment: use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` instead of `!= ""`.  OR, just use an incremental counter to determine which lap you are on

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
var labels = new []{displayLaps1, displayLaps2, displayLaps3, displayLaps4}
var firstEmptyLabel= labels.FirstOrDefault(l => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l.Text));
if(firstEmptyLabel!= null){
    firstEmptyLabel.Text = elapsedTime;
}
```

Note that you would need a clear button or some other method to clear the labels if you want to be able to reset.

I would also consider adding times to a list and show that in the UI. That way it you could keep however many laps you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a lap counter instead

```
int lap = 0;

private void lapButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lap++;

        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
        ts.Milliseconds / 10);

        switch(lap)
        {
           case 1:
             displayLaps1.Text = stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString();
             break;
           case 2:
             displayLaps2.Text = stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString();
             break;
           ...
        }
    }
```